# Regular Expression - get value from string based on criteria

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string delimited with underscores:

id_name_type_environment

which would give me something like this:

- 123456_MyName_x_dev
- 123456_AnotherName_y_dev

basically based on the type I need to get the name. Rather than doing string parsing and substrings I would like to do this using a regex which would do If type = x then extract the name

Is there a simple regex way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(".*_(.*)_x_.*");
        string incomingValue = @"123_NAME_x_dev";
        string inside = null;
        Match match = regex.Match(incomingValue);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            inside = match.Groups[1].Value;
        }
```

This should get the name if the type=x, you can change it to match type=y of course

Comment: Accepted this answer as just my preference though user16484 answer was just as acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Get the type like this:

```
var value = Regex.Match("123456_MyName_x_dev", @"(?<=^\w+_\w+_)\w+(?=_\w+$)").Value
```

And get name like this:

```
var value = Regex.Match("123456_MyName_x_dev", @"(?<=^\w+_)\w+(?=_\w+_\w+$)").Value
```